# How do I install homebrew on mac?

Tags: ruby, macos, installation, homebrew, command-prompt

I tried the command

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/Library/...
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
==> The following directories will be made group writable:
/usr/local/include
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
==> The following directories will have their group set to admin:
/usr/local/include
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

but I have no idea what that means...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have XCode and Command Line Tools installed? If so, the above script should have done it.

Go to the terminal and type

```
brew doctor
```

This will tell you the status of your install.